# function with a property that will be added later

Tags: typescript

This is an example from a book *Programming TypeScript* by Boris Cherny:

```js
type WarnUser = {
  (warning: string): void
  wasCalled: boolean
}

let warnUser: WarnUser = (warning: string) => {
  if (warnUser.wasCalled) {
    return
  }
  warnUser.wasCalled = true
  alert(warning)
}
warnUser.wasCalled = false
```

We have a function with a property that will be added after the creation of the function. When I place this code into a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA6ghgJwHYFUDOEFQLxQN4BQUUAFAO6JICWSA5gFxRrAI20CUjAbgPZUAmRKBTQBhOABsJEfowBGPHtLhICAXwIFpwYZXSZG8ZPqy5ylNo2as67HAD58QqgDNSFYxgQA6EeKkydoTExAgQwACuyEIaxB6oXr5wYpLS-DhQLBEQQpKYwObIbOzqBPEmSSkB6bgukhhAA), TypeScript complains that *`wasCalled` is missing*, but the book says it shouldn't:

> Note that TypeScript is smart enough to realize that though we didn’t assign `wasCalled` to `warnUser` when we declared the `warnUser` function, we did assign `wasCalled` to it right after.

What is going on?

Comment: The TypeScript playground runs the latest version of TypeScript; your book likely doesn't. Might be part of it.

Comment: Use the `function` syntax and you'll get full support from the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `let warnUser` by `const warnUser` so that Typescript knows the function will never be redefined elsewhere.

```js
type WarnUser = {
  (warning: string): void
  wasCalled: boolean
}

const warnUser: WarnUser = (warning: string) => {
  if (warnUser.wasCalled) {
    return
  }
  warnUser.wasCalled = true
  alert(warning)
}
warnUser.wasCalled = false
```

Comment: Fair enough, but if you `function`, you don't need the interface. TypeScript will allow you to add properties to functions declared thusly.